# I just Upgrade Spring boot 2.7.4 to 3.0.0 but then some packages(jasypt, reactive-mongo) doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot

After change to Spring boot 3.0.0

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
```

Error message below was occured by jasypt didn't work, so can't decrypt the encrpyted string in application.yml

Ex)

```
 data:
    mongodb:
      uri: ENC(/XyOV0SVXea4LMvYgQlJpEY8a~~)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:303) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.0.jar:?]
```

Is there any solutions for this? good package for encrypt properties or succesfully load jasypt

PS) There is the other problem for but maybe after jasypt works well it works fine, I guess

```
Error creating bean with name 'reactiveMongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reactiveMongoTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveMongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource
```

I tried to find other package or solve the jasypt but there is no solution for this (caused by spring boot 3.0.0)

Comment: report to vendor of library or wait till packages updated. consider if it's actually necessary to update project to next major version so soon, since major version  released recently

Comment: another option download source of library and try to migrate code base  to support spring boot 3

Comment: @ProblemSlover The recent version of jasypt is 1.9.3 but it was last updated at 2020.01.16 ,,,, maybe there is no major update, Do u know the good package for instead of jasypt?

Comment: if there is not alternative. download library source code and migrate code base to support newer springboot version